# Korean characters are displayed as empty boxes on JTextField

Tags: java, swing, localization, internationalization, jtextfield

`JTextfield` does not show korean charaters properly. It shows empty boxes in instead of characters. Here is the screenshot of my application.

[image: boxes instead of Korean charaters]

Comment: which font do you use on it ?

Comment: changing your font would hopefully solve the problem.

Comment: It is configurable, i will ask the customer about the font. thanks for the advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats because of the fonts that you used.

According to this [oracle document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/intl/font.html) Korean letters is not supported by **Lucida** font.

> Note that of the writing systems that are generally fully supported by
>   the JRE, the Lucida fonts do not support Chinese (Simplified), Chinese
>   (Traditional), Japanese, and Korean.

So if you use the fonts that support the korean language, it will work properly.