# Japanese and Korean characters are not displayed well

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried looking at this post [Korean characters are displayed as empty boxes on JTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42244385/korean-characters-are-displayed-as-empty-boxes-on-jtextfield) This is a closer one but not fits my actual issue.
I have a text box where it accepts japan or korean input depending on user langauge selection.
When the user tries to input japan or korean characters, this is diplayed in some what wierd way and words are getting scattered.
Below is the image how Korean characters are getting diplayed in a wierd way.
[image: Korean input scattered]

Font I have used is
 `font:0px 'Arial Unicode MS',sans-serif,'hanja','kanji'`

Can anyone aware of this kind and help me out ? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If `tofu` boxes are being displayed u can use the noto sans font in google. Just an example `src` will have to be changed according to you. You can download the font or use google's [noto sans](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Noto+Sans). [Getting started](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started).

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Noto Sans";
    src: url("../fonts/noto/sans/regular.eot");
    src: url("../fonts/noto/sans/regular.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), 
         url("../fonts/noto/sans/regular.woff2") format("woff2"),
         url("../fonts/noto/sans/regular.woff") format("woff"),
         url("../fonts/noto/sans/regular.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```

Comment: Tried including on every page. No luck though
hope it should work for korean too ?

Comment: see google, you can download the font, i have show just example. works chinese, japanese, korean & more.

Answer (score 0):

1. 'hanja' and 'kanji' are not font family so typing them in that way would not help
2. The problem here seems to be input instead of display. For Korean input, user typically type multiple character parts and let the input method to compose those parts, is the input box somehow preventing this from happening?